# Test if function or method is normal or asynchronous

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-3.5, coroutine

How can I find out if a function or method is a normal function or an async function? I would like my code to automatically support normal or async callbacks and need a way to test what type of function is passed.

```
async def exampleAsyncCb():
    pass

def exampleNomralCb():
    pass

def isAsync(someFunc):
    #do cool dynamic python stuff on the function
    return True/False

async def callCallback(cb, arg):
    if isAsync(cb):
        await cb(arg)
    else:
        cb(arg)
```

And depending on what type of function gets passed it should either run it normally or with await. I tried various things but have no idea how to implement `isAsync()`.

Comment: But... but `True/False` is dividing by `0`! :O

Comment: Note that any given asynchronous function could be either **coroutine function** or **asynchronous generator function** , please see my answer for detail

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module of Python.

`inspect.iscoroutinefunction(object)`

> Return true if the object is a coroutine function (a function defined with an async def syntax).

This function is available since Python 3.5.
The module is available for Python 2 with lesser functionalities and certainly without the one you are looking for: [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)

Inspect module as the name suggests is useful to inspect a whole lot of thing. The documentation says

> The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods, functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects. For example, it can help you examine the contents of a class, retrieve the source code of a method, extract and format the argument list for a function, or get all the information you need to display a detailed traceback.
>
> There are four main kinds of services provided by this module: type checking, getting source code, inspecting classes and functions, and examining the interpreter stack.

Some basic capabilities of this module are:

```
inspect.ismodule(object)
inspect.isclass(object)
inspect.ismethod(object)
inspect.isfunction(object)
```

It also packs capability to retrieve the source code

```
inspect.getdoc(object)
inspect.getcomments(object)
inspect.getfile(object) 
inspect.getmodule(object)
```

Methods are named intuitively. Description if needed can be found in documentation.

Comment: Is there a practical difference between `inspect.iscoroutinefunction()` and `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction()`?

Comment: @M.I.Wright - no, it is not. Based on the source code of Python 3.6, `asyncio` version is just a reimport from `inspect` module.

Comment: @AlesTeska I haven't looked at the source, but the py3.7 documentation has a clarification that suggests they are subtly different, specifically: `This method is different from inspect.iscoroutinefunction() because it returns True for generator-based coroutine functions decorated with @coroutine.`

Comment: Good answer - two suggestions: 1) mention `inspect.isawaitable`, like one of the other answers does - it checks a slightly different thing but covers certain other cases, and noting the tradeoffs would make for a more comprehensive answer, and 2) the aside about the Python 2 backport should probably either be expanded to note that `async`/`await` don't even exist in Python 2, or else left out entirely.

Comment: @hallo They're not identical, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.iscoroutinefunction : `different from inspect.iscoroutinefunction() because it returns True for generator-based coroutine functions decorated with @coroutine.`

Comment: FYI, if class C is callable, and that might be async, e.g. `async def __call__`, and `c = C()`, you want to check `inspect.iscoroutinefunction(c.__call__)`, not `inspect.iscoroutinefunction(c)`

Comment: Building on @SamH.'s comment: so the Correct ahead-of-time check is actually both: `inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f) or inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f.__call__)`. The former only detects functions with `async` and the latter only detects class instances with an `async` `__call__` method. And neither of these have the same 100% coverage that you get by doing `inspect.isawaitable` on the return value of `f()` (without `await` - you can do `await` on the return value later, once you know it's awaitable).

Answer (score 70):

If you don't want to introduce another import with `inspect`, `iscoroutine` is also available inside `asyncio`.

```
import asyncio

def isAsync(someFunc):
    return asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(someFunc)
```

Comment: The `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction()` function does *two* tests; it uses `inspect.iscoroutinefunction()` first, and if that test fails tests if the function is a function with the [`@acyncio.coroutine` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine) applied. Take this into account!

Comment: i wonder how the supported versionset of this solution compares to the accepted one.  note there are further solutions in other answers.

Answer (score 45):

**TLDR**

If you want to check something should be used with `await`, use `inspect.isawaitable` (as when you test something being `callable()` other than just being a function).

Unlike `iscoroutine` or `iscoroutinefunction` it will also work for `Future`s and objects that implement `__await__` method.

---

**Detailed**

Solutions above will work for simple cases, when you pass coroutine function. In some cases you may like to pass *awaitable object* function that acts like coroutine function, but is not coroutine function. Two examples is [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future) class or *Future-like object* class (class that [implements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) `__await__` magic method). In this cases `iscoroutinefunction` will return `False`, what is not you need.

It's easier to understand on non-async example with passing non-function callable as callback:

```
class SmartCallback:
    def __init__(self):
        print('SmartCallback is not function, but can be used as function')

callCallback(SmartCallback)  # Should work, right?
```

Back to async world, a similar situation:

```
class AsyncSmartCallback:
    def __await__(self):
        return self._coro().__await__()

    async def _coro(self):
        print('AsyncSmartCallback is not coroutine function, but can be used as coroutine function')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

await callCallback(AsyncSmartCallback)  # Should work, but oops! iscoroutinefunction(AsyncSmartCallback) == False
```

Way to solve it not to use `iscoroutine` or `iscoroutinefunction`, but use `inspect.isawaitable` instead. It works with ready object so you must create it first. In other words, solution I would advise to use:

```
async def callCallback(cb, arg):
    if callable(cb):
        res = cb()  # here's result of regular func or awaitable
        if inspect.isawaitable(res):
            res = await res  # await if awaitable
        return res  # return final result
    else:
        raise ValueError('cb is not callable')
```

It's more universal (and I'm sure logically correct) solution.

Comment: But would't that change behavior if a normal function is passed as callback that happens to return an awaitable object, in that case the returned object would also get awaited/executed. Like `def testcb(): return AsyncSmartCallback`

Comment: @Ecko in case you'll pass this `testcb`, result you'll got is `AsyncSmartCallback` as it should be, nothing would be awaited. It happens because `AsyncSmartCallback` is *not* awaitable object, it's class that returns awaitable object: `AsyncSmartCallback()` - this is awaitable object. In case your function `def testcb(): return AsyncSmartCallback()`, this object would be awaited. But I see nothing wrong with it: imagine you pass `def testcb(): return Callback()` - in that case `Callback()` would also be executed.

Comment: I like that callable option at the end. The second could also be written in one function as `def __await__(self): return (yield from asyncio.sleep(1).__await__())`

Comment: if the callback `cb()` is a blocking sync function, this will block the entire event loop, no?

Comment: @MikeTwo sure. It's assumed that OP understands it and won't pass long-running sync callbacks.

Comment: As for python 3.9, async def functions are not recognized by inspect.isawaitable:
```
    >>> async def f(): pass
    ... 
    >>> inspect.isawaitable(f)
    False
```

Comment: @makeroo I was confused at first, everything is correct: `f` is not awaitable, but `f()` is. `inspect.isawaitable(f()) True`

Comment: You're right @MikhailGerasimov, problem is, I found this API confusing.

Comment: nit: `arg` is not passed to `cb`

Answer (score 25):

Co-routines have the `COROUTINE` flag set, bit 7 in the code flags:

```
>>> async def foo(): pass
>>> foo.__code__.co_flags & (1 << 7)
128   # not 0, so the flag is set.
```

The value 128 is stored as a constant in the `inspect` module:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.CO_COROUTINE
128
>>> foo.__code__.co_flags & inspect.CO_COROUTINE
128
```

The [`inspect.iscoroutinefunction()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.iscoroutinefunction) does just that; test if the object is a function or method (to ensure there is a `__code__` attribute) and test for that flag. See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.1/Lib/inspect.py#L180-L187).

Of course, using `inspect.iscoroutinefunction()` is the most readable and guaranteed to continue to work if ever the code flags were to change:

```
>>> inspect.iscoroutinefunction(foo)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Extend the answers above. There has been [4 types of functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-generators) since python 3.6 :

- function
- generator function
- coroutine function
- asynchronous generator function

If your application does not have prior knowledge about the type of the given function, it could be one of them above, the asynchronous function could be either **coroutine function** or **asynchronous generator function** .  `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(someFunc)` only checks whether a function is coroutine function, for asynchronous generator, you can use `inspect.isasyncgenfunction()`. The sample code is shown below :

```py
import inspect, asyncio

def isAsync(someFunc):
    is_async_gen = inspect.isasyncgenfunction(someFunc)
    is_coro_fn = asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(someFunc)
    return is_async_gen or is_coro_fn
```

Comment: There's also e.g. `partial(some_async_func, ...)` which is neither of those. Seems a heuristic is the closest we can get as we try to guess whether it returns an awaitable without actually calling it. I wonder whether `async def f() -> Awaitable` would make `partial(...)`, etc easier to detect.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the other answers here to satisfy this. At least in py 3.10:

```py
class Foo:
    async def __call__():
        pass

foo = Foo()
asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(foo)  #  produces False.
```

instead, to test you can do:

```py
asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(foo) or asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(foo.__call__)
```

Note that:

```py
async def bar():
    pass

asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(bar.__call__)  # produces False
```

In my own code I used to have a lot of:

```py
if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(foo):
    await foo()
else:
    foo()
```

a clearer pattern where you want to handle either could be:

```py
async def if_coro(result):
    if asyncio.iscoroutine(result): # or inspect.iscoroutine,... and so on
        return await result
    else:
        return result

result = await if_coro(async_func())  # result is as expected
result = await if_coro(sync_func())  # result is as expected
```

There is likely many different variations of the above.

Comment: Thank you. Having to call a function to determine if it is async is not always practical (calling it may have unwanted side effects), and knowing how to handle async functors is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

What about applying EAFP here:

```
try:
    result = await cb()
except TypeError as err:
    if "can't be used in 'await' expression" in str(err):
        result = cb()
    else:
        raise
```

this also solves the problem, when cb is an instance of partial as well

Known limitations:

- sync function returning an awaitable. In this case the logic will fail

Comment: I think the problem with this is that if `cb` is a non-async regular function which returns an awaitable for eg. then the `try` block would succeed and you would be actually awaiting the result of `cb()` (which is an awaitable) although `cb` itself is a normal function. That may not be what you desired - maybe you wanted to collect the awaitable result form calling `cb()` but not await that yet.

Answer (score 0):

use `asyncio.iscoroutine()` for judging coroutine,
and `asyncio.isfuture()`for judging task or future

```
import asyncio


async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    print(1)

async def main():
    t = task()
    print(type(t))# <class 'coroutine'>
    print(asyncio.iscoroutine(t)) # True
    print(asyncio.isfuture(t)) # False
    await t

async def main2():
    t = asyncio.create_task(task())
    print(type(t)) # <class '_asyncio.Task'>
    print(asyncio.iscoroutine(t)) # False
    print(asyncio.isfuture(t)) # True
    await t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.run(main2())
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer by `Mikhail Gerasimov`

```py
import inspect

async def asyncify(res):
    """
        mix sync and async code.
        f can be sync or async:
        res = await asyncify(f())
    """
    if inspect.isawaitable(res):
        res = await res
    return res
```

coming from javascript, it is surprising that
in python, `await` fails on non-awaitable objects

in javascript, `await` is a noop on non-awaitable objects:

```js
function f() { return 1; }
async function main() { return await f(); }
await main();
```