# How require that an abstract method is a coroutine?

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-asyncio

How can I require that an abstract base class implement a specific method as a coroutine. For example, consider this ABC:

```
import abc

class Foo(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def func():
        pass
```

Now when I subclass and instantiate that:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def func():
        pass

b = Bar()
```

This succeeds, although `func` is not `async`, as in the ABC. What can I do so that this only succeeds if `func` is `async`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if function or method is normal or asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076619/test-if-function-or-method-is-normal-or-asynchronous)

Comment: That question is about how to test, which is only part of the solution. I want to do this using an abstract base class.

Comment: You have to define `async def func()` again in class `Bar`. `@abc.abstractmethod` does not take in considerate if `func()` is async or not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm asking if there is a way to make this work, short of writing a custom meta class.

Comment: Testing function `func()` inside class `__init__()` is a way but it is not what you want!

Comment: Python doesn't check the signature of overridden method. You can add new parameter or change return type. It's discouraged but possible.
*sync*/*async* dichotomy adds nothing new -- controlling overridden signature is up to user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `__new__` and check if and how a child class has override parent's coros.

```
import asyncio
import abc
import inspect


class A:    

    def __new__(cls, *arg, **kwargs):
        # get all coros of A
        parent_coros = inspect.getmembers(A, predicate=inspect.iscoroutinefunction)

        # check if parent's coros are still coros in a child
        for coro in parent_coros:
            child_method = getattr(cls, coro[0])
            if not inspect.iscoroutinefunction(child_method):
                raise RuntimeError('The method %s must be a coroutine' % (child_method,))

        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *arg, **kwargs)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def my_func(self):
        pass


class B(A):

    async def my_func(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('bb')


class C(A):

    def my_func(self):
        print('cc')

async def main():
    b = B()
    await b.my_func()

    c = C()  # this will trigger the RuntimeError
    await c.my_func()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

### Caveats

- a child class may override `__new__` as well to suppress this constraint
- not only `async` may be awaited. For example

  ```
  async def _change_in_db(self, key, value):
      # some db logic
      pass

  def change(self, key, value):
      if self.is_validate(value):
          raise Exception('Value is not valid')
      return self._change_in_db(key, value)
  ```

  it's ok to call `change` like

  ```
  await o.change(key, value)
  ```

  Not to mention `__await__` in objects, other raw Futures, Tasks...

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful, both the solution and the caveats!

Comment: I think it's important to add that passing `*args` and `**kwargs` to `__new__` instead of `__init__` isn't recommended. as Python 3.3+ will most likely throw an error if you do so.

Comment: AFAIR https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.`__new__` can accept arguments other than the first class (3.3+ doesn't throw any error), `__new__` is a function like any other so why wouldn't is work. The `__init__` is initlializer of an object, while here is the approach that uses class creation - such a different things.