# python-asyncio TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using a third party module to retrieve data from an API. I simply would like to asynchronously await the module to return the data which occasionally takes several seconds and freezes up my app. However, when I try to await a call to that module I receive the TypeError:

`TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression`

```
import thirdPartyAPIwrapper

async def getData():
    retrienveData = await thirdPartyAPIWrapper.data()
    return await retrieveData

def main():
    loop = asncio.get_event_loop()
    data = loop.run_until_complete(getData())
    loop.close
    return data
```

Why can I not await a type('dict')? Is there a way around this?
If async/await with asyncio will not work with a third party module that doesn't return a coroutine then what are my other options?

Comment: yes, when looking at the source of that module it is a normal `def` function

Comment: this is trivial in the static case, when the object type is known: add or remove the `await` keyword. for the dynamic case, when the object type is unknown, see [Test if function or method is normal or asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076619/test-if-function-or-method-is-normal-or-asynchronous/36077430#36077430)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Only asynchronous (defined with `async def`) functions can be awaited. Whole idea is that such functions are written special way what makes possible to run (`await`) them without blocking event loop.

If you want to get result from common (defined with `def`) function that takes some considerable time to be executed you have these options:

- rewrite this whole function to be asynchronous
- call this function in another thread and await for result asynchronously
- call this function in another process and await for result asynchronously

Usually you want to choose second option.

Here's example of how to do it:

```
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)


def sync_blocking():
    time.sleep(2)


async def hello_world():
    # run blocking function in another thread,
    # and wait for it's result:
    await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, sync_blocking)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(hello_world())
loop.close()
```

Please, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) about how asyncio works. I think it'll help you much.

Comment: Note, that unlike Javascript Python isn't created with asynchronicity in mind. In Python if you do something asynchronous you'll need to do it explicitly: explicitly to define asynchronous functions in particular. Common function can't just become asynchronous without efforts. That's a reason why you'll need thread to run synchronous function asynchronously.

Answer (score 10):

You do not need to await which function is running asynchronously

```
async def getData():
    retrienveData = thirdPartyAPIWrapper.data()
    return retrieveData
```

Answer (score 8):

As `thirdPartyAPIWrapper.data()` is a normal sync function you should call it in another thread.

There is a helper function for that in a `asgiref` library.
Assume we've got a blocking function with an argument:

```
import asyncio
import time

from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


def blocking_function(seconds: int) -> str:
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f"Finished in {seconds} seconds"

async def main():
    seconds_to_sleep = 5
    function_message = await sync_to_async(blocking_function)(seconds_to_sleep)
    print(function_message)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

There is also an `async_to_sync` helper function in that library.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing test cases and I need to mock async functionality. So, you can write a simple helper function like so.

```py
async def resolve(val):
    return val
```

Now you can await anything

```
foo = resolve(1) 
await foo # No error!
```

Comment: Doesn't address long running sync process from third party