# FastAPI, Pytest TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I am writing an API using FastAPI when I run with uvicorn everything is normal, I get the error when I want to run a test using the FastAPI TestClient.

This is the error:

```
async def get_user_id(conn, user):
   collection = conn.CIA.get_collection("Employees_Info")
   user = await collection.find_one({'name':user},{"_id":1, "name":0, "password":0})
   TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression
db\db.py:12: TypeError
```

project structure:

```
APP
 |--__init__.py
 |--run.py
 |--main.py
 |--test
    |--test_app.py
 |--routes
    |--router.py
 |--models
    |--models.py
 |--db
    |--db_conn.py
    |--db.py
 |--auth_jwt
    |--jwt_auth.py
 |--auth
    |--auth.py
```

This is the code of the test, I am using mongomock, I don't know if this will be the root of the problem:

```
import collections
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import status
from main import app
from mongoengine import connect, disconnect, get_connection
from db.db_conn import db


client = TestClient(app)

connect('mongoenginetest', host='mongomock://localhost', alias='testdb')
db.client = get_connection('testdb')
db.client["CIA"]
db.client["Employees_Info"]
db.client.CIA.Employees_Info.insert_one({"name": "user_Name","password": "week"})

def test_ping():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Conectado"}
   
def test_login():
    data = {"username":'user_name', 'password':'week'}
    response = client.post("/login", data=data)
    assert response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    db.client.disconnect()
```

I tried performing the Async test according to the FastAPI documentation but it doesn't work either, if I use the "normal" database the test works.

router.py

```
@router.post("/login", tags=["user"], response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), 
                                 db: AsyncIOMotorClient = Depends(get_database)):
    authenticate_user_id = await authenticate_user(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not authenticate_user_id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"user_id": str(authenticate_user_id["_id"])})
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

auth.py

```
async def authenticate_user(conn:AsyncIOMotorClient, username, password):
    user_id = await verify_user(conn, username)
    if not user_id:
        return False
    
    if not await verify_password(conn, user_id, password):
        return False
    
    return user_id

async def verify_user(conn, user):
    return  await get_user_id(conn,user)

async def verify_password(conn, user_id, password):
    return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, await get_password(conn, user_id))
```

db.py

```
async def get_user_id(conn, user):
    collection = conn.CIA.get_collection("Employees_Info")
    user = await collection.find_one({'name':user},{"_id":1, "name":0, "password":0})
    print(type(user))
    if user:
        return user

async def get_password(conn, user_id):
    collection = conn.CIA.get_collection("Employees_Info")
    db = await collection.find_one(user_id)
    if db:
        return db['password']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-asyncio TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822552/python-asyncio-typeerror-object-dict-cant-be-used-in-await-expression)

Comment: I'm guessing the mocked version doesn't support async (i.e. the `await` call is made on a regular returned value from the mock, instead of actually awaiting the method call).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need install pytest-asyncio.Here more info https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles across this question, as I have, here is the way to fix the problem.

```
import asyncio
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

import pytest
from bson import ObjectId


def async_return(result):
    f = asyncio.Future()
    f.set_result(result)
    return f


@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestCase(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_case(self):
        mock_data = {'_id': ObjectId('65eb252e54348fc7d1d9d137'), 'name': 'badah'}
        with patch('motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorCollection.find_one', return_value=async_return(mock_data)):
            result = await repository.get(name='badah')
            assert result == mocked_result
```

In this code, we ensure that the mock **find_one** method returns an awaitable object, by defining it as an asyncio.Future.

Answer (score -1):

`collection.find_one()` is not a async function, so you are trying to await the result of the function which is a dict, that is why you are getting the error `TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression` you are awaiting a dict, not a coroutine which would be returned by an async function.

To fix you code just remove `await` from

```py
db = await collection.find_one(user_id)
```

When you do that, you won't really need it to be a async function, so you can just define it regularly, but you will than have to change all the function calls and remove the `await` from them, otherwise you will get this error again

##### Full code:

db.py

```py
def get_user_id(conn, user):
    collection = conn.CIA.get_collection("Employees_Info")
    user = collection.find_one({'name':user},{"_id":1, "name":0, "password":0})
    print(type(user))
    if user:
        return user


def get_password(conn, user_id):
    collection = conn.CIA.get_collection("Employees_Info")
    db = collection.find_one(user_id)
    if db:
        return db['password']
```

auth.py

```py
def authenticate_user(conn:AsyncIOMotorClient, username, password):
    user_id = verify_user(conn, username)
    if not user_id:
        return False
    
    if not verify_password(conn, user_id, password):
        return False
    
    return user_id


def verify_user(conn, user):
    return get_user_id(conn,user)


def verify_password(conn, user_id, password):
    return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, get_password(conn, user_id))
```

router.py

```py
# This probably has to stay as an async function, I'm not sure how the module works
@router.post("/login", tags=["user"], response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), 
                                 db: AsyncIOMotorClient = Depends(get_database)):
    authenticate_user_id = authenticate_user(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not authenticate_user_id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"user_id": str(authenticate_user_id["_id"])})
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

```py
import collections
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import status
from main import app
from mongoengine import connect, disconnect, get_connection
from db.db_conn import db


client = TestClient(app)

connect('mongoenginetest', host='mongomock://localhost', alias='testdb')
db.client = get_connection('testdb')
db.client["CIA"]
db.client["Employees_Info"]
db.client.CIA.Employees_Info.insert_one({"name": "user_Name","password": "week"})

def test_ping():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Conectado"}
   
def test_login():
    data = {"username":'user_name', 'password':'week'}
    response = client.post("/login", data=data)
    assert response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    db.client.disconnect()
```

Comment: He is using Motor (conn:AsyncIOMotorClient) and `collection.find_one()` in Motor is async.

https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_collection.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCollection.find_one