# Why do I keep getting the error "TypeError object dict_keys can't be used in 'await' expression"

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small asynchronous application, based on a well-working code from [GitHub here](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/py/async-fetch-order-book-from-many-exchanges.py). I tried to alter it a little to fit my needs in this way

*main.py*

```
import asyncio
from kernel.init import Init
async def main():
    init = Init()
    await init.loadSymbols()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

*init.py*

```
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt


class Init:
    async def loadSymbols(self):
        symbols_list = {}
        for exchange_id in ['poloniex', 'binance']:
            exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
            exchange = exchange_class()
            try:
                await exchange.load_markets()
                symbols_list[exchange_id] = await exchange.markets.keys()
            except Exception as e:
                print(type(e).__name__, str(e))
            await exchange.close()
        return symbols_list
```

But when I start, I get this error

> TypeError object dict_keys can't be used in 'await' expression

Of course, I Googled for a long time, and based on similar examples ([link 1](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/1869), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822552/python-asyncio-typeerror-object-dict-cant-be-used-in-await-expression)) on the Internet, I tried to fix my code.
*Attempt one*

```
class Init:
    async def loadSymbols(self):
        symbols_list = {}
        for exchange_id in ['poloniex', 'binance']:
            exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
            exchange = exchange_class()
            try:
                await exchange.load_markets()
                input_coroutines = exchange.markets.keys()
                symbols_list = await asyncio.gather(*input_coroutines, return_exceptions=True)
            except Exception as e:
                print(type(e).__name__, str(e))
            await exchange.close()
        return symbols_list
```

But in this case I get an error

> TypeError An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

*Attempt two*

```
input_coroutines = [list(exchange.markets.keys())[0]]
```

I used almost all the tips that I found with a similar problem on the Internet (I will not write them below so that the question does not look too big), however, not one of them did not work for me. Please can you tell me how to get rid of this error - I have completely given up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try after removing await before exchange.markets.kesy() like

```py
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt

class Init:
    async def loadSymbols(self):
        symbols_list = {}
        for exchange_id in ['poloniex', 'binance']:
            exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
            exchange = exchange_class()
            try:
                await exchange.load_markets()
                symbols_list[exchange_id] = exchange.markets.keys()
            except Exception as e:
                print(type(e).__name__, str(e))
            await exchange.close()
        return symbols_list
```

because I see in the source code that self.markets is a simple dictionary

```py
#https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/async_support/base/exchange.py#L705

def set_markets(self, markets, currencies=None):
    values = []
    self.markets_by_id = {}
    # handle marketId conflicts
    # we insert spot markets first
    marketValues = self.sort_by(self.to_array(markets), 'spot', True)
    for i in range(0, len(marketValues)):
        value = marketValues[i]
        if value['id'] in self.markets_by_id:
            (self.markets_by_id[value['id']]).append(value)
        else:
            self.markets_by_id[value['id']] = [value]
        market = self.deep_extend(self.safe_market(), {
            'precision': self.precision,
            'limits': self.limits,
        }, self.fees['trading'], value)
        values.append(market)
    self.markets = self.index_by(values, 'symbol')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's completely right, `exchange.markets.keys()` appears to be a normal set of dict keys, not something populated by a coroutine. Try dropping it entirely: `symbols_list[exchange_id] = exchange.markets.keys()`

Debugging, I see exchange.markets.keys() containing a normal set of dictionary keys:
`dict_keys(['BTS/BTC', ..., 'WFAI/USDT'])`. If it were a coroutine, it would say something like:  `<coroutine object dict_keys at ...>`

You should never need to do this, but to help you understand: if you wanted to turn a normal function into an async, you could wrap it:

```
import asyncio
def fn(x):
    return x + 1


async def fn_def(x):
    return x+1

def deferrer(some_fn):
    async def deferred(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return deferred


deferred_fn = deferrer(fn)

print(fn(3))
print(asyncio.run(fn_def(3)))
print(asyncio.run(deferred_fn(3)))
```